# Is it valid HTML to have a button within a select list?

Tags: html, user-experience

I need to make a `select` list of languages for website. Choosing an option will translate the website. This isn't hard to code but I'm wondering what is the correct markup, especially considering accessibility.

Would this be OK:

```
<select>
  <option>
    <a role="button">
      English
    </a>
  </option>
  <option>
    <a role="button">
      French
    </a>
  </option>
  <option>
    <a role="button">
      Italian
    </a>
  </option>
</select>
```

UPDATE To clarify my requirements. I need something that looks like a select list - so only 1 option is visible until you click it. I could just use a `ul` and style it with CSS but then I'm hiding the other options and Id have to create some sort of modal, so I was hoping there was a simpilar way. You also wouldn't have the nice native handling of select lists on mobile devices.

I've made a demo showing the UX id like to achieve:

https://codepen.io/_j_i_m_fb_/pen/gOpOYGV

```
<select>
  <option>English</option>
  <option>French</option>
</select>

const SELECT = document.querySelector('select');

const changeLanguage = language => {
  console.log('Language is now ', language)
}

SELECT.addEventListener('change', (e) => changeLanguage(e.target.value));
```

Comment: No, you wouldn't put a button in an option. The option has ARIA definitions for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listbox_role

Comment: Run it through a validator. But no, what you have there is not valid.

Comment: Why don't you just go with what your demo shows?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's invalid HTML. The most common approach for this was to code a `select`, like:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <!-- some more options -->
</select>
```

and make sure that this `select` is invisible. Then, you can code some HTML template, which looks like select and upon doing some user action on the elements, an `onclick` or a click handler would something like

```
document.getElementById("country").val(this.innerText);
```

Example:

```
<div onclick='document.getElementById("country").val(this.innerText);'>English</div>
```

Comment: @connexo you are surely right. However, I would be interested to know the reason. If there is a valid reason, then I will do an edit, or, if the answer is unsalvagable to remove it. Without a reason being given it's difficult to use the wisdom behind it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.

> Error: Stray start tag a.

— https://validator.nu/

If you want a list of buttons, then use a list (`<ul>`) of buttons (`<button>`), but if you want a list of links (and it is common to implement a language switcher by linking to another page in a different language) then use a link (`<a href="this-page-in-french.html" hreflang="fr">`) not a button.